# Build from APK and build from project android in eclipse

Tags: android, build, onresume

At the moment,I have an android project.

When I build direct in eclipse use Run as->Android Application.App run well.When i open app and go to a other activity in app.Then click home button and open app again.resuming last Activity.

When I build by get file APK in bin and paste to SDCard and build file APK..Then open app,go to an other activity in app,click home,open app again. It always start app again,not resume last activity.

Are there different when build direct by eclipse and build by APK in SDCard?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in place in your activity ?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: No.My activity is have onResume().

Comment: Having an onResume that only calls super.onResume is equivalent to not overriding it at all.

Comment: My app have a tab activity and it contain sub activity in each tab.And in tab activity and each sub tab ,i always declare onResume and call super.onResume().